# "According to the answer we provide of this question, we will offer radically different approaches to this problem"

Tags: vocabulary, phrase-usage, expressions

The scenario I want to describe: for instance, if you believe that human nature is like so, you will solve this social tension in a particular way, but if you see human nature in another way you will provide a *completely* different solution to this social tension.

To rephrase, I'm talking about the opinion we have in regard to the answer. Depending on your opinion about human nature, you will propose a specific answer to solve this specific social issue. If you had a completely different perception of human nature you would have proposed a completely different answer to this same social issue.

Here is what I have so far:

> According to the answer(answer A) we provide of this question (A), we will offer radically different approaches to this problem (B).

According to our opinion (answer A) about human nature (question A), we will bring this or this answer (answer B) to solve this this specific social issues (question B)

Comment: It's still not clear why you would say _we provide_.  To whom would _we_ be providing an answer?  Are you speaking of what opinion _we_ have in regard to the question? Or of what _we_ think is the answer? That might be more like a _stance_ on an _issue_, or a _viewpoint_. not an _answer_.

Comment: @BrianHitchcock thanks for your patience! I updated again.

Comment: Great edits @GuillaumeCombot - thanks for taking the time to clarify the situation that you're trying to describe. I've edited again to make it a bit clearer and to tidy up the English a little, I definitely believe it can be answered now.

Comment: @starsplusplus thanks for your great help! I kept your changed, but the tittle was off topic. I'm looking for a grammatical correction. I just took the human nature topic to illustrate my question.

Comment: @GuillaumeCombot Yes, I understood that. However, proofreading is off-topic here so you need to explain that you are looking for how to describe this specific concept (people providing different approaches to the problem depending on their beliefs of the problem). I think your example sentence is too unclear for people to understand what you mean from that alone. Would you consider using the title I suggested before but with the "human nature" part removed? Maybe something like, "How do I express the concept of people providing different approaches depending on their beliefs of the problem?"

Comment: @starsplusplus Yes without "human nature" it would work. I guess I'm lacking stand back from my question. And by the way I'm touched by your impressive humility. Thanks a lot!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The scenario you have described is people having *different beliefs* about *what the problem is*. Or, perhaps, what the cause of the problem is.

For example, let's say there is a problem with young people [mugging](http://www.thefreedictionary.com/mugging) the elderly in a certain district after dark.

- Alice thinks this is because there aren't enough policemen in the area, and she proposes employing more policemen, or maybe ensuring that policemen patrol that area after dark.
- Bob thinks that the problem is that the young people are bored and don't have anything better to do, so he proposes building a youth centre.
- Whereas Chris thinks that the problem is that young people nowadays don't have any respect for the elderly, and he thinks that the problem can be solved by educating the young people, or forcing them to do [community service](http://www.thefreedictionary.com/community+service) in an [old people's home](http://www.ldoceonline.com/dictionary/old-people-s-home) so that they gain respect for the elderly.

Because Alice, Bob and Chris have different opinions on the cause of the problem, they all think there is a different way to solve it.

Here are a number of ways you could express this concept:

> Depending on the way we view the situation, we will offer radically different approaches to this problem.

Alice *views the situation* differently to Bob. She sees it as a crime problem, and thinks it can be fixed by law enforcement. Bob and Chris both think it is more of a social problem, and both offer solutions to try and stop the young people from *wanting* to mug the elderly.

> Depending on our opinions on the root cause of the problem, we will offer radically different approaches to solving it.

Bob and Chris both agree that the route to the solution is through interaction with the young people themselves. However, they disagree on the root cause. Bob thinks the root cause is boredom and Chris thinks that the root cause is lack of respect. So they both approach the solution in different ways.

> Depending on our views on human nature, we will offer radically different approaches to solving this problem.

Alice, Bob and Chris all have different views on human nature. For example, Bob thinks that people are more likely to commit crimes if they don't have anything better to do. This means that he thinks giving them something better to do is a solution to the problem. Chris thinks that people are less likely to commit crimes if they respect the victim, so he thinks that cultivating this respect is a means of prevention. Alice thinks that the way to prevent crimes is simply to provide less opportunities for the crimes to take place, so she thinks that having policemen patrol the area will be a good deterrent. Because of their different views on human nature, they all offer different ways to solve the social problem.

Comment: @starplusplus could you please confirm the gerund, for this one: "and will thus offer radically different approaches **to solving** social tension" why not the infinitive? ("To solve social tension)

Comment: @GuillaumeCombot I'm not sure I can do that question justice right now, it would probably be better to pose it as a new question.

Answer (score 1):

I agree that context is missing.  However, assuming that the **question** and **problem** have been discussed in text occurring before this sentence, how about this:

> Depending on the answer to this **question**, we will offer radically
>   different approaches to (addressing/solving) this **problem**.

or if it's important that the answer comes from you:

> Depending on the answer we provide for this **question**, we will offer
>   radically different approaches to (addressing/solving) this **problem**.

Comment: I did not know we could "address a problem", and the "approach to address**ing** looks even more weird (for a french: address has a totally different meaning). In brief thanks for these great clarification!